# How do you render the depth buffer of objects with displaced vertices?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl, depth-buffer

I've modified this example: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Fireball.html

and inserted:

```
var depthShader = THREE.ShaderLib["depthRGBA"];
var depthUniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(depthShader.uniforms);
depthMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
     fragmentShader : depthShader.fragmentShader,
     vertexShader : depthShader.vertexShader,
     uniforms : depthUniforms
});
depthMaterial.blending = THREE.NoBlending;

depthTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, {
    minFilter : THREE.NearestFilter,
    magFilter : THREE.NearestFilter,
    format : THREE.RGBAFormat
});

quadCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / -2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / -2, -1000, 2000);
quadCamera.position.z = 100;

var shader = THREE.UnpackDepthRGBAShader;
var uniforms = new THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);
uniforms.tDiffuse.value = depthTarget;
quadMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader : shader.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader : shader.fragmentShader,
    uniforms : uniforms
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight*1.5), quadMaterial);
mesh.position.z = -500;
mesh.position.y = 200;
quadScene = new THREE.Scene();
quadScene.add(mesh);
```

And changed the render function to :

```
function render() {
   renderer.overrideMaterial = depthMaterial;
   renderer.render(scene, camera, depthTarget, true);
   renderer.overrideMaterial = null;
   renderer.render(quadScene, quadCamera);
}
```

and it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty46e.png

1. How do I get the depth buffer to look like a depth buffer and not be black?
2. Will custom ShaderMaterials that displace vertices write correctly to depthbuffer? Because I have another project with objects of displaced vertices and the depth doesn't account for the displacement. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it is strange that the plane is black, too. Because in your theory, wouldn't the plane be correctly colored if it was for displaced vertices only?

Maybe the camera near and far clip plane values are off? Thus it is not working with the depth correctly. Have you checked that the near and far values are in a sane range?